# How can we get sentinel entities from logs what is the KQL Query we to for Entities , Sentinel ID information

Tags: logging, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-sentinel

Need KQL Query to logs for Entities , Sentinel ID, Created Date

Created Date
Sentinel ID
Entities
Last Updated
User Assigned information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to [SecurityEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/securityevent) that contains the columns list of SecurityEvent Table, from there you can select the columns from the table within the query.

Use project command of
**KQL**:

```
SecurityEvent 
| project TimeGenerated, CreatedDate, ResourceID
```